# Linux mp3 publish tag writer

Tags: linux, centos, mp3

am searching for mp3 cli tag writer for linux ( centos ) which can add publisher tag , searching from few days tried a lot of cli writers but all of them have basic options like title , artist , album , genre , comment 
what am interested as publisher tag so any idea which tool can help me with it 
no gui only cli as am on centos have to link it to php 
thanks

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of searching i found mid3v2 which can write v2 tags on mp3

```
yum install python
yum install pip
pip install mutagen
```

by running it

```
$ mid3v2 -h
Usage: mid3v2 [OPTION] [FILE]...

Mutagen-based replacement for id3lib's id3v2.

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         be verbose
  -q, --quiet           be quiet (the default)
  -e, --escape          enable interpretation of backslash escapes
  -f, --list-frames     Display all possible frames for ID3v2.3 / ID3v2.4
  --list-frames-v2.2    Display all possible frames for ID3v2.2
  -L, --list-genres     Lists all ID3v1 genres
  -l, --list            Lists the tag(s) on the open(s)
  --list-raw            Lists the tag(s) on the open(s) in Python format
  -d, --delete-v2       Deletes ID3v2 tags
  -s, --delete-v1       Deletes ID3v1 tags
  -D, --delete-all      Deletes ID3v1 and ID3v2 tags
  --delete-frames=FID1,FID2,...
                        Delete the given frames
  -C, --convert         Convert tags to ID3v2.4 (any editing will do this)
  -a "ARTIST", --artist="ARTIST"
                        Set the artist information
  -A "ALBUM", --album="ALBUM"
                        Set the album title information
  -t "SONG", --song="SONG"
                        Set the song title information
  -c "DESCRIPTION":"COMMENT":"LANGUAGE", --comment="DESCRIPTION":"COMMENT":"LANGUAGE"
                        Set the comment information
  -g "GENRE", --genre="GENRE"
                        Set the genre or genre number
  -y YYYY[-MM-DD], --year=YYYY[-MM-DD], --date=YYYY[-MM-DD]
                        Set the year/date
  -T "num/num", --track="num/num"
                        Set the track number/(optional) total tracks
```

mp3 tags can be written like

```
mid3v2 -a "artist" --TPUB "company name" 'path/file.mp3'
```